# Android 10 and higher Scoped Storage app crashes, upload image to server

Tags: android, android-10.0, android-11, scoped-storage

I am trying to upload image to server from gallery or camera using retrofit.
My App is working fine upto android 10 where i have opted scoped storage by using,

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

But in android 11 it is removed so what chnges should i make to fix the error of scoped storage

```
 2021-02-13 15:46:39.335 13981-13981/com.nixbin.MeetNepali W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to build unique file: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures Title image/jpeg
2021-02-13 15:46:39.337 13981-13981/com.nixbin.MeetNepali W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2079)
2021-02-13 15:46:39.337 13981-13981/com.nixbin.MeetNepali W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2039)
2021-02-13 15:46:39.337 13981-13981/com.nixbin.MeetNepali W/System.err:     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:188)
2021-02-13 15:46:39.337 13981-13981/com.nixbin.MeetNepali W/System.err:     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
2021-02-13 15:46:39.337 13981-13981/com.nixbin.MeetNepali W/System.err:     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:495)
2021-02-13 15:46:39.338 13981-13981/com.nixbin.MeetNepali W/System.err:     at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1854)
2021-02-13 15:46:39.338 13981-13981/com.nixbin.MeetNepali W/System.err:     at android.provider.MediaStore.createPending(MediaStore.java:627)
2021-02-13 15:46:39.338 13981-13981/com.nixbin.MeetNepali W/System.err:     at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media.insertImage(MediaStore.java:1802)
2021-02-13 15:46:39.338 13981-13981/com.nixbin.MeetNepali W/System.err:     at com.nixbin.MeetNepali.application.MyApplication.getImageUri(MyApplication.java:280)
2021-02-13 15:46:39.338 13981-13981/com.nixbin.MeetNepali W/System.err:     at com.nixbin.MeetNepali.fragments.DiscussionFragment.onActivityResult(DiscussionFragment.java:295)
2021-02-13 15:46:39.338 13981-13981/com.nixbin.MeetNepali W/System.err:     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:170)
2021-02-13 15:46:39.338 13981-13981/com.nixbin.MeetNepali W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8140)
2021-02-13 15:46:39.338 13981-13981/com.nixbin.MeetNepali W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4969)
2021-02-13 15:46:39.338 13981-13981/com.nixbin.MeetNepali W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5017)
2021-02-13 15:46:39.338 13981-13981/com.nixbin.MeetNepali W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
2021-02-13 15:46:39.338 13981-13981/com.nixbin.MeetNepali W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
2021-02-13 15:46:39.338 13981-13981/com.nixbin.MeetNepali W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
2021-02-13 15:46:39.338 13981-13981/com.nixbin.MeetNepali W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2123)
2021-02-13 15:46:39.338 13981-13981/com.nixbin.MeetNepali W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
2021-02-13 15:46:39.338 13981-13981/com.nixbin.MeetNepali W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
2021-02-13 15:46:39.338 13981-13981/com.nixbin.MeetNepali W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7710)
2021-02-13 15:46:39.338 13981-13981/com.nixbin.MeetNepali W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2021-02-13 15:46:39.338 13981-13981/com.nixbin.MeetNepali W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
2021-02-13 15:46:39.338 13981-13981/com.nixbin.MeetNepali W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

show Dialog to choose galley or camera

```
public void uploadImageTypePost() {
   //set image path
    setimagepath();
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            getActivity());

    // set title
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Choose option");

    // set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Please select image from ")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Camera",
                    (dialog, id) -> {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        if (hasCameraPermission()) {
                            takePicture();
                        } else {
                            requestCameraPermission();
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("Gallery",
                    (dialog, id) -> {
                        if (hasGalleryPermission()) {
                            openGallery();
                        } else {
                            requestGalleryPermission();
                        }

                    });

    // create alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
    // show it
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Set Image path function

```
private void setimagepath() {

    String fileName = "IMG_" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date()) + ".jpg";
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        File sdIconStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "Pictures/");
        // create storage directories, if they don't exist
        sdIconStorageDir.mkdirs();

        mFileTemp = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "Pictures/", fileName);
    } else {
        mFileTemp = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir(), fileName);
    }
}
```

Open Gallery

```
    private void openGallery() {
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY);
}
```

Take Picture

```
private void takePicture() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    try {
        Uri mImageCaptureUri = null;
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        mImageCaptureUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(),
                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                mFileTemp);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PICTURE);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("", "cannot take picture", e);
    }
}
```

On Activity Result

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        try {

            final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            final InputStream imageStream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
            final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(selectedImage, 500, 500, true);
            filepath = getPath(getActivity(), getImageUri(getActivity(), resized));
            Utils.loadImageRound(getActivity(), profileImage, filepath);
            Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: " + filepath);


            //Absolute Path

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "PickUp image failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        try {
            filepath = mFileTemp.getAbsolutePath();
       
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), Uri.fromFile(new File(mFileTemp.getAbsolutePath())));
            Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 500, 500, true);
            System.out.println("image width" + resized.getWidth() + " image height" + resized.getHeight());
            filepath = getPath(getActivity(), getImageUri(getActivity(), resized));

            filepath = getPath(getActivity(), getImageUri(getActivity(), resized));
            Utils.loadImageRound(getActivity(), profileImage, filepath);

            Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: " + filepath);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("exception...." + e.toString());
        }
  } else {
//            Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Permission Denied Goto Settings and allow storage and camera permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

get path

```
public static String getPath(Context context, Uri uri) {
    String[] data = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(context, uri, data, null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Thank you in advance for helping!

Comment: Which statement causes your exception?

Comment: Delete `getPath()`. Also, `ACTION_PICK` does not take a MIME type  -- if you want the user to choose content by MIME type, use `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` or `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`. Beyond that, when posting questions to Stack Overflow involving crashes, post *the entire stack trace*, not just one line.

Comment: ` filepath = getPath(getActivity(), getImageUri(getActivity(), resized)); `. THis is causing exception

Comment: I have added stack trace of exception.@CommonsWare